# Python trouble with piping ssh using Popen

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I am writing a python script that uses plink to ssh into a linux box, execute a command, then write the output of that command to a string and return to my python script.

I would also like to not print the commands I am running to the terminal.

I have the following which executes the command and prints to terminal, but it does not return to my python script, nor can I figure out how to store the output of my command to a string.

```
while(True):
network_name = raw_input('\nEnter test network: ')
network_name_check = raw_input('\nYou want to test on the %s network. Is this correct? (Y/N): ' %(network_name))
if inputYNChecker(network_name_check):
    print "\nVerifying Network exists as Group_Name on Control VM..."
    sshCommand = "plink root@Control -pw PASSWORD"
    lsCommand = "ls -1 --color=never -d */ | grep " + network_name +"\n"
    sshProcess = Popen(sshCommand,shell=False,stdin=PIPE)
    sshProcess.stdin.write("cd /mnt/PCAPS/GroupSetup\n")
    #sshProcess.communicate("cd /mnt/PCAPS/GroupSetup\n")
    sshProcess.stdin.write(lsCommand)
    sshProcess.stdin.write("exit\n")
    sshProcess.stdin.close()
    break
print "Back to python script"
```

I guess I really don't understand how pipes work, as when I have `stdin=PIPE` and `stdout=PIPE`, nothing is displayed in terminal except for "Using username "root"." and then it gets hung up.

How can I:

a) Not display the commands I'm sending to the ssh session

b) Store the output of the commands (which would be a folder name) to a string

c) return to my original python program

Comment: Have you considered using a library made for this task, such as `paramiko` or `fabric` ?

Comment: to cature the output of a `Popen` you just specify `stdout=PIPE` and then read from `shProcess.stdout`  But you have `shell=False`, are you saying that opening the popen shows a terminal?